when using Flatlist / map in react /react native then the item's component state is not updated correctly
when using Flatlist / map in react /react native then the item's component state is not updated correctly


Problem :-

parent component
<FlatList
  data={itemList}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <Item item={item} />}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
/>;

**Item component(Child):-
**
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Checkbox } from "native-base";

function Item({ item }) {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(item.status === 1); // <<< -- at the time of rendering Item component isChecked value is not updated correctly

  const toggleCheckbox = () => {
    setIsChecked(!isChecked);
  };

  return (
    <Checkbox
      alignSelf={"flex-start"}
      mt={1}
      size="md"
      value={item.name}
      accessibilityLabel="Task checkbox"
      isChecked={isChecked} // <<-- state value is not updating that's why it's not checked / uncheck the checkbox when item card is populated
      isDisabled={isChecked} // <<-- same here
      onChange={toggleCheckbox}
    />
  );
}


export default Item;`


Solution :-

just replace the keyExtractor inside parent component's FlatList with uniqe key name like (id / name)
keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)} 
to this
keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
      <FlatList
        data={itemList}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Item
            item={item}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id} //<<<---- Here not use **index** insted use **id**
      />


Instead of update the item data of the rowItem update the itemList:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Checkbox } from "native-base";

function Item({ item }) {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(item.status === 1); // <<< -- at the time of rendering Item component isChecked value is not updated correctly

  const toggleCheckbox = () => {
    setIsChecked(!isChecked);
  };

  return (
    <Checkbox
      alignSelf={"flex-start"}
      mt={1}
      size="md"
      value={item.name}
      accessibilityLabel="Task checkbox"
      isChecked={isChecked} // <<-- state value is not updating that's why it's not checked / uncheck the checkbox when item card is populated
      isDisabled={isChecked} // <<-- same here
      onChange={toggleCheckbox}
    />
  );
}

Update item list:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Checkbox } from "native-base";

function Item({ item }) {
  
  const toggleCheckbox = () => {
    const updatedItemList = itemList.map((listitem, index)=>{

    if(item.id === listitem.id) {
     return {...item, status: !item.status}
    }

    return listitem;
   )

   setItemList(updatedItemList);
  };

  return (
    <Checkbox
      alignSelf={"flex-start"}
      mt={1}
      size="md"
      value={item.name}
      accessibilityLabel="Task checkbox"
      isChecked={isChecked} // <<-- state value is not updating that's why it's not checked / uncheck the checkbox when item card is populated
      isDisabled={isChecked} // <<-- same here
      onChange={toggleCheckbox}
    />
  );
}


export default Item;

